# Sweetalert2 IE9 error 'oninput'

Tags: javascript, promise, sweetalert2

My site has a Sweetalert prompt that asks for the user's name once they login.  Works fine in Chrome, Safari, Edge and IE11 (not tested IE 10 yet) but on IE9 I get this error...

SCRIPT5007: Unable to set value of the property 'oninput': object is null or undefined

The initial ajax call is working and the correct values are returned by the Sweetalert asking for their name doesn't happen.  If I remove the Sweetalert and just include the ajax call within the if statement, the user can log in successfully.

```
if(logged_in === '0' || active === 'no'){
    swal({
        title: 'Please enter your name',
        type: 'question',
        text: 'This is to inform other users of your account who is currently logged into it',
        input: 'text',
        showCancelButton: true,
        inputValidator: function (value) {
            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                if (value) {
                    resolve();
                  } else {
                    reject('Please enter your name');
                }
            });
        }
    }).then(function (result) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax/common_ajax.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: 'action=login&user='+userID+'&session='+session+'&name='+result,
            success: function(response) {
              if (response.result === 'success'){
                 window.location.replace(response.lastPage);
              }
            }
        });
    });
}
```

The line the debugger picks up is `swal({` I suspect the problem is the `Promise` which I have included..

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/core-js/2.4.1/core.js"></script>
<script src="js/sweetalert2.min.js"></script>
```

I know that the values `logged_in` and `active` that are passed through the initial if statement are correct but I don't know where to go from here.  I would love dearly to just tell users to update their browser but the problem is a lot of my user base work for corporates that don't allow users to update their own systems etc so that isn't an option.

Comment: SweetAlert2 doesn't have and never had IE9 support: https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2#browser-compatibility

Comment: @LimonMonte fair enough and thanks for your help